Como programar una formula a partir de datos importados de Excel?
Estoy apenas adentrandome en Python y empece a manejar parte de la libreria de pandas.
Estoy tratando de introducir la siguiente formula a Python:
Log(R35) = 0.732 + 0.588 log(k) – 0.864 log(ø)
A partir de unos datos de Excel que he importado:

Quiero tomar los datos de la columna Por y Per para meterlos en la formula. Mi pregunta aqui es; Como puedo meter estos datos a Python? Como puedo indicarle que solamente quiero los datos de esas dos columnas? Y sobretodo, Como vizualizar los resultados obtenidos por la ecuacion?
Adjunto el codigo que hasta ahorita he usado:
import pandas as pd 

df_Hoja1 = pd.read_excel(io = 'C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/PittWin/Pittwin_001/Ejercicio.xlsx',
                        sheet_name = 'Hoja1',header = 3,names = None,index_col = None,
                        usecols = 'C:H',engine = 'openpyxl')

df_Hoja1.head() 

 

print(df_Hoja1)

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda.
Saludos a todos!

Como puedo meter estos datos a Python? Como puedo indicarle que solamente quiero los datos de esas dos columnas? Y sobretodo, Como vizualizar los resultados obtenidos por la ecuacion? Lo primero de todo es aprender a manejar este sitio ya que haces múltiples preguntas en una sola publicación. Abre 1 pregunta por cada problema que tengas

Si lo que buscas es aplicar:
0.732 + 0.588 * log(k) - 0.864 * log(Φ)

a cada fila del dataframe, dónde:
log -> logaritmo en base 10
k   -> valor de la columna Per(k)
ø   -> valor de la columna Por(Φ) 

simplemente necesitas usar numpy.log() para vectorizar la operación. Seleccionar una columna en pandas es trivial, simplemente dataframe["nombre de columna"]
Partiendo de tu ejemplo:
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO("""\
Muestas,Distancia (m),Volumen,Por(Φ),Per(k),Por Hel(%)
M111,3250,12.5,0.256,5.845,25.56
M112,3258,10.5,0.268,2.548,26.78
M113,3270,8.4,0.248,0.786,24.67
M114,3284,7.6,0.211,0.451,21.11
M115,3295,8.1,0.235,1.284,23.44
M116,3912,11.3,0.201,2.156,20.08
M117,3937,14.8,0.198,0.266,19.71
M118,3956,13.7,0.287,1.256,13.68
M119,3966,7.6,0.145,4.564,14.41
M120,3981,8.6,0.186,3.251,18.52 
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)

Ahora tenemos el siguiente DataFrame:
>>> df

  Muestas  Distancia (m)  Volumen  Por(Φ)  Per(k)  Por Hel(%)
0    M111           3250     12.5   0.256   5.845       25.56
1    M112           3258     10.5   0.268   2.548       26.78
2    M113           3270      8.4   0.248   0.786       24.67
3    M114           3284      7.6   0.211   0.451       21.11
4    M115           3295      8.1   0.235   1.284       23.44
5    M116           3912     11.3   0.201   2.156       20.08
6    M117           3937     14.8   0.198   0.266       19.71
7    M118           3956     13.7   0.287   1.256       13.68
8    M119           3966      7.6   0.145   4.564       14.41
9    M120           3981      8.6   0.186   3.251       18.52

Para aplicar la fórmula simplemente puedes hacer:
m35 = 0.732 + 0.588 * np.log(df["Per(k)"]) - 0.864 * np.log(df["Por(Φ)"])

esto genera una Serie con el resultado de aplicar la operación por cada fila:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m35 = 0.732 + 0.588 * np.log(df["Per(k)"]) - 0.864 * np.log(df["Por(Φ)"])
>>> m35

0    2.947432
1    2.419649
2    1.795109
3    1.608078
4    2.130207
5    2.569979
6    1.352574
7    1.944532
8    3.293104
9    2.878485
dtype: float64

Si quieres agregarla como una columna al dataframe original:
>>> df["M35"] = m35
>>> df

  Muestas  Distancia (m)  Volumen  Por(Φ)  Per(k)  Por Hel(%)       M35
0    M111           3250     12.5   0.256   5.845       25.56  2.947432
1    M112           3258     10.5   0.268   2.548       26.78  2.419649
2    M113           3270      8.4   0.248   0.786       24.67  1.795109
3    M114           3284      7.6   0.211   0.451       21.11  1.608078
4    M115           3295      8.1   0.235   1.284       23.44  2.130207
5    M116           3912     11.3   0.201   2.156       20.08  2.569979
6    M117           3937     14.8   0.198   0.266       19.71  1.352574
7    M118           3956     13.7   0.287   1.256       13.68  1.944532
8    M119           3966      7.6   0.145   4.564       14.41  3.293104
9    M120           3981      8.6   0.186   3.251       18.52  2.878485

En tu caso seria:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_Hoja1 = pd.read_excel(
    io='C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/PittWin/Pittwin_001/Ejercicio.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    header=3,
    names=None,
    index_col=None,
    usecols='C:H',
    engine='openpyxl'
)

df_Hoja1["M35"] = 0.732 + 0.588 * np.log(df_Hoja1["Per(k)"]) - 0.864 * np.log(df_Hoja1["Por(Φ)"])

print(df_Hoja1)

El nombre de tu columna parece ser "Por(Φ)", donde la letra griega parece ser Phi mayúscula, si te da un KeyError asegúrate de que el nombre de la columna es el correcto.
